# Executable application using netbeans and mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I made a project using netbeans and mysql.
15 classes are there under default package with main.java as main class.
And now i want to show my project in college and they want only executabe  file
How can i make this.

Jar file create ho ri h but its not accessing database i kept contents of manifest as shown below and copied in folder where my other .class files are kept and i had also placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar in same folder still not working

Main-Class: login
Class-Path: . mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the main class in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF like so:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

after you have done this your frind can double click the .jar file you create.